No audio nor video in i3wm manjaro
I couldn’t make my bluetooth headphones work as in pavucontrol, the only output devices I had are speakers and headphones (unplugged). I tried installing things to solve it, but I made it worse:
$ history
  424  sudo pacman -Syu
  425  sudo pacman -Syu
  426  exit
  427  sudo pacman -S pavucontrol
  428  pavucontrol
  429  sudo pacman -S pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  430  sudo pacman -S pulseaudio 
  431  ls .config
  432  mv ~/.config/pulse/ Downloads/pulse
  433  systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
  434  reboot
  435  diff Downloads/pulse/ .config/pulse/
  436  rm -rf .config/pulse/
  437  mv Downloads/pulse/ .config/pulse
  438  systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
  439  pactl list | grep -C2 A2DP
  440  pacmd list-cards
  441  pacmd list-sinks
  442  dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
  443  alsamixer
  444  amixer -c 0 scontrols
  445  pulseaudio -k
  446  pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
  447  pactl
  448  sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
  449  pavucontrol --show-all-sinks
  450  pavucontrol --restart
  451  sudo pacman -S bluez-libs bluez-alsa
  452  yay -S pulseaudio-bluetooth-git
  453  yay -R pulseaudio-bluetooth-git
  454  sudo pacman -R pulseaudio-bluetooth-git
  455  sudo pacman -S bluez-libs
  456  yay -S bluez-alsa-git
  457  sudo systemctl status bluetooth
  458  pacman -Qqt
  459  pacman -Q bluez
  460  sudo hciconfig hci0 down
  461  hciconfig hci0 down
  462  reboot
  463  pacmd dump; pactl list cards
  464  pamac install manjaro-pipewire
  465  reboot
  466  sudo pacman -R manjaro-pipewire
  467  sudo pacman -R pipewire
  468  sudo pacman -Rns pipewire gst-plugin-pipewire pipewire-alsa pipewire-audio pipewire-pulse telegram-desktop wireplumber xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-wlr
  469  sudo pacman -Rns pipewire
  470  sudo pacman -Rns  gst-plugin-pipewire pipewire-alsa pipewire-audio pipewire-pulse telegram-desktop wireplumber xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-wlr
  471  sudo pacman -S pulseaudio 
  472  reboot
  473  bluetoothctl devices
  474  pactl list sinks short
  475  pactl list sinks short
  476  pactl list sinks short
  477  blueman
  478  sudo pacman -S blueman
  479  blueman-manager
  480  lxappearance
  481  history
  482  history
  483  yay -R pulseaudio-bluetooth-git
  484  sudo pacman -R pulseaudio-bluetooth-git
  485  sudo pacman -R pulseaudio-bluetooth
  486  sudo pacman -R bluez-alsa-git
  487      sudo pacman -R manjaro-pipewire
  488  sudo systemctl status bluetooth
  489  pavucontrol --restart
  490  pulseaudio --restart
  491  sudo systemctl status bluetooth
  492  sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
  493  sudo systemctl start bluetooth
  494  alsamixer
  495  sudo pacman -R pipewire
  496  alsamixer
  497  alsamixer
  498  exit
  499  xterm
  500  xprop
  501  urxvt
  502  qt5ct
  503  sudo pacman -S ffmeg
  504  sudo pacman -S ffmpeg
  505  sudo pacman -R ffmpeg

Most of these commands didn’t work, I was trying anything I saw online. The output is that audio stopped working and now, any video or audio also fails to run. I tried videos on qutebrowser, chromium, vlc and whatsdesk, and an audio on vlc and whatsdesk.
For further information, I run in my i3-config file “exec --no-startup-id volumeicon”, but when I start using my pc, it stops working and disappears, but I can open it myself. Also, when I open alsamixer, I can see that the default card is pipewire now (which wasn’t before)

I don't know why, but I checked my latest changes in my home directory and found that .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini and .gtkrc-2.0 had the following change:
-gtk-icon-theme-name=Papirus-Dark-Maia
+gtk-icon-theme-name=breeze-dark

Going back to the Papirus-Dark-Maia icon theme solved the audio and video problem. However it didn't solve the bluetooth output, and vlc video stopped working.
